# Запрос mysql с выборкой по дате

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `courier` вида:

```
region,
courier,
date_from,
date_to
```

`date_from` и `date_to` - это даты, с какого по какое курьер занят.

На данную страницу с формы приходит запрос тоже с двумя датами - нужно сделать выборку всех курьеров, которые были в это время в работе.
Как это сделать?

Comment: что значит в "это время". Все это время или хотя бы одну секунду из этого времени ?

Comment: в каком формате хранится время в базе и в каком формате вы передаете из формы?

Comment: *которые были в это время в работе* Достаточно касания? обязательно пересечение? обязательно полное покрытие?

Comment: Врямя в базе datetime, из формы - datetime-local, Курьер выехал и поехал в другой город - если я нажимаю кнопку - получить курьеров в работе с такого - по такое время - все курьеры которые были в поездке выводятся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю правильно вас понял или нет, если что поправьте

```
$date_from = strtotime($_POST['date_from']);
$date_to   = strtotime($_POST['date_to']);

$result = "SELECT region, courier, date_from, date_to 
    FROM courier
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) >= '{$date_from}' 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_to) <= '{$date_to}'";
```

Comment: Что то не работает. С формы приходит запрос в виде 2017-01-01T00:00
а в таблице ячейка типа datetime и значения вида 2018-01-01 05:00:00.
Может дело в букве Т в запросе с формы?

Comment: Подправляю, спасибо!
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_from) >= '{$dateFromOutput}' 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_to) <= '{$dateToOutput}'